# Saving state of onClickListener?

Tags: android, onclick, savestate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save state of onClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514994/how-to-save-state-of-onclicklistener)

My program implements several onClick listeners. I need a way to save which onClick listener the user left off at before they exit the program and then come back into it. I want them to be at the same onClick they were before they left.